# 1 domain with 3 cpanels based on url (not subdomain) (same vps)

Tags: .htaccess, dns, cpanel

The example is the easiest way I can explain.

```
domain.com/cpanel-1 (is on same VPS but cpanel #1)
domain.com/cpanel-2 (is on same VPS but cpanel #2)
domain.com/cpanel-3 (is on same VPS but cpanel #3)
```

This is because I built one site which is secure and the others are wordpress sites that are probably outdated and I don't want my site to get hacked because of the other outdated sites I didn't build.

I know this can be done with a subdomain but that's not the idea.
Any ideas are appreciated or if that's just not possible.